# html click, except element AND children

Tags: jquery

So what I'm trying to accomplish is that you close the popup by clicking anywhere outside of it. But as it is now, if you where to click on a < p> tag inside the popup, it also closes...

What I've got now is this:

```
$('html').click(function(e) {
    var popup = $('.popup');

    if(popup.length) {
        if(!$(e.target).is('.popup-content') || !$(e.target).is('.popup-content').find('*')) {
            popup.removeClass('in');

            setTimeout(function () {
                popup.remove();
            }, 300);
        }
    }
});
```

Obviously !$(e.target).is('.popup-content').find('*') doesn't seem to work.
And the content will not be static...

Hopefully someone has a solution

Comment: Can you show your html please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('html').click(function(e) {
    var popup = $('.popup');
    var clickedElement = e.target;
    var popupContent = ($(clickedElement).closest('.popup-content').length > 0)? true:false;
    if(popup.length > 0) {
        if(!popupContent) {
            popup.removeClass('in');

            setTimeout(function () {
                popup.remove();
            }, 300);
        }
    }
});
```